# Show "scan credit card" in standalone web app after page navigation

Tags: html, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, ios-standalone-mode

I have a 2 page registration/membership microsite. The second page contains a form for collecting credit card information. When tapping the CC number I want the 'Scan Credit Card' button in the top left to show.

Here's the input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cardNumber" data-encrypted-name="number" autocomplete="off" name="addCreditCardNumber">
```

**Scenario #1 - WORKS**

In mobile Safari, when tapping the CC number input field, the scan card button shows in the keyboard.

**Scenario #2 - WORKS**

If I create an app icon (by selecting 'Add to Home Screen') for the second page on the iPad and launch the web app, when I tap the CC number field, the scan card button shows in the keyboard.

**Scenario #3 - FAIL**

If I create an app icon from the FIRST page on the iPad and launch the web app, fill out the info, and POST the form to the second page, when I tap the CC number field, the scan card button DOES NOT show in the keyboard.

All pages are hosted on a secure site and on the same domain.

Any thoughts??